# ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this._icon.imageSource.ios')

Tags: ios, nativescript, markers, nativescript-google-maps-sdk

I'm trying to get custom marker icon on map. I have used nativescript-google-maps-sdk v^2.9.1 and I'm getting following error.

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///node_modules/@nativescript/core/image-source/image-source.js:306:0: fromResource() is deprecated. Use ImageSource.fromResourceSync() instead.
CONSOLE ERROR file:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:4002:0: ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this._icon.imageSource.ios')
```

the code added to get marker on map is

```
addMarker(mark, index): void {
    const marker = new Marker();
    marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(mark.latitude, mark.longitude);
    // marker.icon = this.ocean_pin; // default pin
    const is24 = (isIOS ? '_24' : '');
    marker.icon = 'https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/map-marker-2-xxl.png';//'https://mob-app-assets.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/pin_ocean' + is24 + '.png'; // default pin
    this.mapView.addMarker(marker);
    this.mMarkers.push(marker); // to update marker pin when carousel swiped
  }
```

previously I was using icon from assets, and it was working like a charm. Find the code below that was working for icons from assets.

```
import * as imageSource from 'tns-core-modules/image-source';
import { Image } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/image/image';


constructor() {
    super();
    this.buttonHeight = isAndroid ? 45 : 35;
    const is24 = (isIOS ? '_24' : '');
    this.ocean_pin = new Image();
    this.ocean_pin.src = '~assets/icons/pin_ocean' + is24 + '.png';
    this.ocean_pin.imageSource = imageSource.fromFile('~assets/icons/pin_ocean' + is24 + '.png');
    this.pink_pin = new Image();
    this.pink_pin.src = '~assets/icons/pin_pink' + is24 + '.png';
    this.pink_pin.imageSource = imageSource.fromFile('~assets/icons/pin_pink' + is24 + '.png');
  }
```

I don't know what has went wrong. But now it's not working for icons from URL.

Comment: Using fromUrl() also shows method deprecated and shows default pin instead of custom pin from url.

Comment: The deprecated message should not be an issue right now (the author may have to update his code later at some point). The actual issue is that the plugin do not support remote image url. You may have to consider sending a {N} `Image` object pointing to the remote image.